# Deleting individual cron jobs using PHP

Tags: php, cron

I have a php script that sets up a cron job once some data is inserted to a SQL database:

```
<?
$output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
file_put_contents('/tmp/crontab.txt', $output.'* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/dldl1330/public_html/new/mailchimp.php'.PHP_EOL);
echo exec('crontab /tmp/crontab.txt');
?>
```

This cron job executes another script which syncs the SQL DB with mailchimp. In this mailchimp php script it deletes the cron tab:

```
echo exec('crontab -r');
```

Once this happens I loose all jobs in my cron tab (and it removes the email which gets emailed after every cron job), how can I make it so the above line only deletes the `/home/dldl1330/public_html/new/mailchimp.php` cron job?

Comment: You could try reading the entire crontab line by line and match the correct script, remove it and write the new contents back to the crontab.

Comment: You can 'write' it again how you do now, except when you get its contents, just match and remove the tab you want gone, and then write it back to the cron tab

Comment: So I can get the content of the crontab by using:
    $output = shell_exec('/usr/bin/crontab -l');
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";

And I know I need to delete this line - * * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/dldl1330/public_html/new/mailchimp.php

So how do I go about it?

Answer (score 7):

I used the above advise and came up with a solution, I am not sure how efficient or correct it is.... welcome for comments.

Note: The //Find string section is in there just for my debugging/learning purposes

```
<?php
//get contents of cron tab
$output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";

//Find string
$cronjob = ('* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/dldl1330/public_html/new/mailchimp.php');
if (strstr($output, $cronjob)) {
   echo 'found';
} else {
   echo 'not found';
}

//Copy cron tab and remove string
$newcron = str_replace($cronjob,"",$output);
echo "<pre>$newcron</pre>";

file_put_contents('/tmp/crontab.txt', $newcron.PHP_EOL);
echo exec('crontab /tmp/crontab.txt');

?>
```

Comment: Seems like the best solution. I've been looking around online for a bit and simply ending all crons and re starting a new list of them makes the most sense. Thanks!